# Float div to right with variable width before left div in HTML for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

This one has beaten me and I am sure I am missing something simple.

What I am trying to do is have a left sidebar with fixed width and the right filled up with variable width content that will handle responsive design.

The complication comes as I want to have the HTML of the left sidebar come after the right div so that when resolution is down to mobile size I can remove the float and have the content appear before the sidebar and have both with width of 100%

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}
.sidebar {
  background: blue;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Top</div>
<div class="content">Content (right on widescreen, top on less than 750px</div>
<div class="sidebar">Sidebar (left on widescreen, bottom on less than 750px</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5LLhmo8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with calc() .Just add to the .content width: calc(100% - 240px); and you will have the content be responsive and occupy the remaining width.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/a5LLhmo8/1/

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
.content {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 240px);
}
.sidebar {
    background: blue;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: Works a treat and looks like it works on the latest browsers, will check it on iPad when I get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it!

Please check:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
.content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
    width:100%;
    float: ;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Please check the link to see if this is what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/a5LLhmo8/2/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work I am afraid, the content block doesn't fill the full width on the higher resolution

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flexbox design to make your page responsive without the use of media queries and it can provide a lot of flexibility.

HTML:

```html
<div class="header">Top</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
.content {
    width: 300px; /* Specify minimum content width */
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.sidebar {
    background: blue;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here's some information on flexbox design. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The flexbox design works well. http://jsfiddle.net/2kdhrwbu/ The only thing the solution doesn't do is 100% width the sidebar when as small screen size.